# Why select option defaultValue doesnt work?

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, react-context, default-value

I have created context crud app. But there is one problem. I want the bachelor value in the select option to be stored by default if the user does not select any option in the select part. But the problem  is that when no option is selected, it shows as education : ""
I want the first value to be selected even if I don't select any option

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../../context/GlobalState";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import styles from "../ContactForm/Form.module.scss";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { Checkbox, Button, Form, Input, Select, Radio } from "antd";

const Form1 = () => {
  const { ADD_CONTACT } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    fatherName: "",
    specialty: "",
    email: "",
    gender: "",
    updatesNotification: "",
    education: "",
  });

  const { Option } = Select;
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const { name, surname, fatherName, specialty, email } = contact;

  let history = useNavigate();

  const onSubmit = () => {
     if (contact) {
      ADD_CONTACT(contact);
      history("/");
      console.log(contact);
      toast.success("Contact successfully added");
    }
  };

  const selectOptions = [
    { value: "Bachelor" },
    { value:"Master"  },
    {  value:"Phd" },
    {  value: "Doctorate" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Form
        onFinish={onSubmit}
        className={styles.form}
        name="myForm"
        form={form}
        initialValues={{
          remember: true,
        }}
        labelCol={{
          span:5,
          offset:1
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
          offset:3
        }}
      >
          <Form.Item
            label="Name"
            name='Name'
            labelAlign="left"
            style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter your  name!"}]}
          >
            <Input
              placeholder="Enter your name"
              value={name}
              name="name"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Surname"
          name='Surname'
          labelAlign="left"
          style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter your surname!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            placeholder="Enter your surname"
            value={surname}
            name="surname"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Father Name"
          labelAlign="left"
          style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
          name='Father Name'
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter your father name!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            placeholder="Enter your father name"
            value={fatherName}
            name="fatherName"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Email"
          name='Email'
          labelAlign="left"
          style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter your email!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            name="email"
            placeholder="Enter your e-mail"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Specialty"
          name='Specialty'
          labelAlign="left"
          style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter your specialty!"  }]}
        >
          <Input
            name="specialty"
            placeholder="Enter your specialty"
            value={specialty}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item 
        label='Education' 
        name='Education Level' 
        labelAlign="left"
        style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
        >
          <Select
            onChange={(e)=>setContact({ ...contact, education : e })}
            defaultValue={selectOptions[0].value}
            name="education"
            style={{
              width: 120,
              textTransform:'capitalize'
            }}
          >
            {selectOptions.map((item,index) => (
              <Option key={index} value={item.value} ></Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item 
        label="Gender"
        labelAlign="left"
         name='Gender' 
         style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
         rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select your gender!" }]}>
          <Radio.Group
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({
                ...contact,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? e.target.id : "",
              })
            }
            name="gender"
          >
            <Radio
              id="Female"
              value="Female"
              checked={contact.gender === "Female"}
            >
              Female
            </Radio>
            <Radio 
            id="Male" 
            value="Male" 
            checked={contact.gender === "Male"}>
              Male
            </Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item  
        labelAlign="left"
        style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}
        wrapperCol={{
          offset: 1,
          span: 16,
        }}>
          <Checkbox
            name="updatesNotification"
            checked={contact.updatesNotification === "update"}
            id="update"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({
                ...contact,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? e.target.id : "",
              })
            }
          >
            I want to receive information about news
          </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>

        <div className={styles.buttons}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" >
            Add contact
          </Button>
          <NavLink to="/" className="mx-3">
            <Button danger type="primary" >Cancel</Button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form1;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdkSW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the value in the state, this is your problem

```
   const [contact, setContact] = useState({
  id: uuidv4(),
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  fatherName: "",
  specialty: "",
  email: "",
  gender: "",
  updatesNotification: "",
  education: selectOptions[0].value,
});
```